# Can I access last mined block if my node is not there yet?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization

This might be a stupid question, but I'll ask anyway...

I'm currently connected to Ropsten and when I execute `eth.blockNumber` it says `1853682` (I'm like 300000 blocks away from current last mined block).

Is there any way to access the information in a block that's still not downloaded to my copy of the blockchain? I think it's plain impossible, but maybe there's a way...

**Edit:** I want to access the last node programatically from my node, not just query the contents of that last block on an external website (maybe etherscan has an API to make such queries?...)

Thanks so much in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to just view about all the contents of the last mined block it is very much **possible** by using etherscan, the link for which is given below: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

Thank you

Comment: At current time the last mined block in ropsten is https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/2179635

Comment: Hi Kishore! thanks for your quick reply... I'll have to edit the question, I meant to access the last block programmatically from my node. Nevertheless, I use https://ropsten.etherscan.io/ everyday (that's the reason I know what block is the current last) :)

Comment: Ok, Then that said , the mined block details can only be accessed programically

Answer (score 0):

You can query an external node endpoint, like one from Q[uikNode.io](https://www.quiknode.io), while your node syncs.

disclosure: work for QuikNode